# How to insall a database with an application?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010, installation

This seems like it would be easy as pie but it is not. I would like to include a sql server database with my application installation. I see a lot of similar questions, so let me be clear: I know how to set up prerequisites, but I want to include my application's database with the installation.

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I have a project with a local database. I have a setup project. However, when I generate the setup.exe and install the app, no database is generated and the app does not work.

I hope that the answer to this is as simple as it seems it should be. How do I include my application's database with the rest of the application in the setup.exe?

Comment: maybe create a simple script that first calls the db installer and then calls the app installer.

Comment: H2 database perhaps ? This link http://www.h2database.com/html/license.html says "You can integrate it into your applications (including in commercial applications), and you can distribute it."

Comment: I don't get it. How is it that including a database with an application can be difficult when it is core to an application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! My solution:

In the setup project right click the project and select View > File System. Then right click the Application Folder folder and select Add > File...

Then browse to .mdf file, select it and bam! Included in the installation.